# Angular 2 routing issue

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-routing

Can somebody help me with angular 2 routing.
I have 2 pages.. home and search results page.. 
Header for home and search results page are different..
here is my code, I am able to display the home page with header but when I go to search results page, header is not getting replaced with new one..

home.routes

```
 export const HomeRoutes: Routes = [
 { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
 { path: '', component: HomeHeadbarComponent, outlet: 'route1' }
];
```

search.routes

```
export const SearchRoutes: Routes = [
 { path: 'search', component: SearchPanelComponent},
 { path: 'search', component: HeadbarComponent, outlet: 'route1' }
];
```

App.html

```
<router-outlet name="route1"></router-outlet>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it working with the code below..

```
{
    path: 'search',
    children: [
    {
        path: '',
        component: SearchPanelComponent
    },
    {
        path: '',
        component: HeadbarComponent,
        outlet: 'route1'
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your home.routes should be below code this will be redirect to you HomeComponent and if you want to redirect it on SearchPanelComponent both you can use in below code

import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent} from './Home';

export const routes: Routes = [

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'Home', pathMatch: 'full' },

{ path: 'Home', component: HomeComponent}, 

{ path: 'search', component: SearchPanelComponent},
```

];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that happens because you have empty path `path: ''` for the first header, so it could overlap the new one. Could you try with the different path, and check it out, should help.

Comment: same result Mikki.. If I switch components of outlet route 1 and primary, header is replaced.. bottom line is primary outlet is getting replaced but not the second one... My requirement is to replace 2 components based on path

Comment: I mean, to replace empty string with some name, so both routes will have some location path different from empty string

Comment: It's a good point..if I have empty path for both the headers, I will see 2 headers, I need to restrict one header per page... My requirement is to replace 2 components (content and header) based on path

Comment: But if both are not empty , does it work as expected?

Comment: one thing I have noticed is if I have name for header, it is not loading at all.. header is getting loaded only if it has empty string..

Comment: { path: 'test', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'test', component: HomeHeadbarComponent, outlet:'route1' } not displaying header at all.. { path: 'search', component: SearchPanelComponent},
  { path: 'search', component: HeadbarComponent, outlet: 'route1' }